# How to expand text without shifting surrounding elements using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout so that when I click on "See More" to expand the text of one container, the surrounding containers remain in the same position.

There are three containers and each container has two wrappers, a top which contains the title and bottom which contains the image, text and button. I don't know what the length of the titles will be beforehand, so in order to make sure that the boxes, text and button line up, I've given each container *justify-content: space-between* so that the bottom wrappers always align.

The issue arises after clicking "See More", where the bottom wrapper of each container moves down to fit the height of the container.

```css
     .main-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
        }
        .container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .top-wrapper {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          height: 100%;
        } 
        .bottom-wrapper {
          display: flex; 
          flex-direction: column; 
          justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="top-wrapper">
              <div class="title">
                    TITLE 1 IS LONG THAT IT GOES TO NEXT LINE
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom-wrapper">
              <div class="image-text-wrapper">
                  <div class="image-container">
                      <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/000">
                  </div>
                  <div class=“text” id="text">
                   {{ text }}
                   //See More code
                  </div>
              </div>
              <button>
                BUTTON 1
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
         //second container code
      <div>
      <div class="container">
         //third container code
      <div>
    </div>
```

Should I be using a table or is there a simple CSS fix to this?

You can find the full code here: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/It7K0k4dLcE6XCfI)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `.container` class:

```css
.container {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

The `align-self` property allows you to override the setting for `align-items` that is controlling your flex items' alignment.

And adding the following to the `.title` class:

```css
.title {
  min-height: 50px
}
```

You may need to play around with this setting, but it prevents the image from rendering without any space between it and your title.

Caveat: the CSS you included here in your post isn't exactly what I got when I opened your Plunkr link -- the `.container` didn't have `display: grid;` set, but I think this should work nonetheless.

Comment: The `align-self` works really well! Unfortunately, the `min-height` still results in uneven alignment of the content if the title height is greater than the min-height value. If there's a solution to that, I'm yet to find it...

Comment: The min-height solution won't work because I'm fetching the data dynamically and won't know how many lines the titles will cover beforehand. One row of containers may have all one-liner titles but the other may have varying number of lines. (Also edited the CSS to match the plunker - thanks for pointing that out)